# Python module import difference "string.maketrans"

Tags: python, import

I have come across a strange python module import issue.

When I trying to import the [boilerpipe](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe) module,

```
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
```

I got this exception:

```
 Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boilerpipe-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/boilerpipe/extract/        __init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1140, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 58, in <module>
    import textwrap
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 40, in <module>
class TextWrapper:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 82, in TextWrapper
    whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(_whitespace, ' ' * len(_whitespace))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

I've searched over internet and saying that in Python 2.6 the 'str' module has been renamed to 'string' module. So this looks like some where in code library it didn't import "string" module properly.

**Yet the really strange thing is,** when I run the python code from `home` directory and run the same piece of code (either by using `python` shell or using `python pyfile.py`), it works fine! No more import error.

So I'm bit confusing. Can anyone give me any hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other script in `sys.path` is called "string.py" and is masking the stdlib module.

Comment: So what makes it different to run in 'home' directory against to run in other dirs?

Comment: Your home directory doesn't have a string.py.

Comment: yes... that solved my problem. I made a silly mistake. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Double check to make sure that you don't have a file `string.py` that has been imported.

To debug this, put somewhere:

```
import sys
raise Exception("string module: %r" %(sys.modules.get("string"), ))
```

That will tell you what string module was imported (or if it shows `None`, no `string` module has been imported yet).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet there is only one line code regarding this problem: `from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor` . I cannot modify the source code of this external lib. And also, I've checked the string module and got different response when I run python in `home` dir and when I run python in other dirs. Why is it different?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. I just happened to find that I write a "string.py" file myself in some other dirs I tested. Now problem solved. Thanks